# Derivation of index decomposition analysis

Tags: economics, applications

I’m currently reading a paper on index decomposition. The paper is here for reference : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140988315001772

The paper is setting out how it has gone about deriving the index decomposition, and I’m getting a bit lost at the final step. The aim is to decompose the changes in an aggregate variable between time $T$ and time $0$.

We start from the position that we want to break an aggregate category $V$ down into a series $j$ of subcategories, $V_j$, each of which is impacted by a range of $i$ factors over time. So we have :

$$ V(t) = \sum_j^m V_j (t) =  \sum_j^m \big ( \prod_1^i x_{ij}(t)  \big )$$

So what we are interested in is:
$$V(T) - V(0) = \sum_j^m \big ( \prod_1^i x_{ij}(T) \big ) - \sum_j^m \big ( \prod_1^i x_{ij}(0) \big ) $$

We can also consider $V(T) - V(0)$ as:
$$V(T) - V(0) = \int_0^T \frac{dV(t)}{d(t)}$$

Which then leads us to consider $\frac{dV(t)}{d(t)}$, from the definition above we have:

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{dV(t)}{d(t)} = \sum_j^m \frac{dV_j(t)}{d(t)} &=\sum_j^m \bigg( \frac{dx_{1j}(t)}{dt}x_{2j}(t)x_{3j}(t)\cdots x_{nj}(t)+\\ &\qquad\qquad\frac{dx_{2j}(t)}{dt}x_{1j}x_{3j}(t)\cdots x_{nj}(t) + \ldots \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad+\frac{dx_{nj}(t)}{dt}x_{1j}(t)x_{2j}(t)\cdots x_{(n-1)j} \bigg)
\end{split}$$
We can then re-write this as:

$$\frac{dV(t)}{dt} =\sum_j^m \left(  \frac{V_j(t)}{x_{1j}(t)}\frac{dx_{1j}(t)}{dt}+\frac{V_j(t)}{x_{2j}(t)}\frac{dx_{2j}(t)}{dt} + \cdots + \frac{V_j(t)}{x_{nj}(t)}\frac{dx_{nj}(t)}{dt} \right) $$

Which, as  $\frac{d\ln(x_{ij}(t))}{dt}) = \frac{1}{x_{ij}(t)}\frac{dx_{ij}(t)}{dt}$ we can re-write as:

$$ \frac{dV(t)}{dt} = \sum_j^m V_j(t) \left( \frac{d\ln(x_{1j}(t))}{dt}+\frac{d\ln x_{2j}(t))}{dt} +\frac{d\ln(x_{3j}(t))}{dt}+ \cdots + \frac{d\ln(x_{nj}(t))}{dt} \right) $$

Which gives us finally that:
$$V(T)-V(0) = \int_0^T \frac{dV(t)}{dt} = \int_0^T \left(\sum_j^m V_j(t) \left( \frac{d\ln(x_{1j}(t))}{dt}+\frac{d\ln x_{2j}(t))}{dt} +\frac{d\ln(x_{3j}(t))}{dt}+ \cdots + \frac{d\ln(x_{nj}(t))}{dt} \right) \right)$$

It is at this point that the paper state that as the data we want to evaluate the integral over is not continuous (which it's not) we need to use a discrete integration, which gives the solution:
$$V(T)-V(0) = \sum_j^m \left( w_j \cdot \ln \left( \frac{x_{1j}(T)}{x_{1j}(0)} \right) + w_j \cdot \ln \left( \frac{x_{2j}(T)}{x_{2j}(0)} \right) + \ldots + w_j \cdot \ln \left( \frac{x_{nj}(T)}{x_{nj}(0)} \right)  \right)$$

For some weights $w_j$.

At this point I'm lost. I've no idea how we went from the integral to the sum, using some discrete integration, nor what these weights are that have been introduced.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to understand this better?

Thanks for any help,
Hmmm16

Comment: I think I get the idea, but I have doubts concerning the execution. The idea is Lagrange interpolation: $$\int_0^T f(t)dt=\sum_{i=1}^n\left( \int_0^T\prod_{k\neq i} \dfrac{t-t_k}{t_i-t_k}dt\right) f(t_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nw_i f(t_i) $$ where the $t_k$ are the interpolation points for the Lagrange polynomial.

Comment: First $=$ sign should be $\approx$. (edit time exceeded)

Comment: @MariusS.L. thanks for this, when you say doubts about the execution, what are you referring to there? Do you mean my explanation of what's in the paper or the paper itself?

Comment: This entire calculation looks (to me!) like formula acrobatics that economists use to make their calculations look complicated whereas nothing happens at all. A discrete i.e. numerical integration uses interpolation, Newton's formula, or the trapezoid formula. I do not see any interpolation steps on [0,T], only start and end. That would be a rectangle: $T \cdot V_{max}$. What he does with the $x_{ij}$ looks like Lagrange interpolation messed up. I would test the entire thing with an example. My attempts to prove $\int_0^T V_j(t) d\ln x_{ij}(t)=w_j \ln(x_{ij}(T)/x_{ij}(0))$ failed ...

Comment: ... by integration by parts. An entire term was missing. Then I looked into discrete integration and found interpolation, but no interpolation in the text. My strategy would be some invented $V,x_{ij}$ and a test calculation. I think there are some hidden assumptions. Or it is way easier: $\int_0^T V_j (x_{ij}'(t)/x_{ij}(t)) dt =V_j\log (x_{ij}(T)/x_{ij}(0)).$ This is true as long as $V_j$ does not depend on $t.$ It seems that the author smuggled the dependency on $t$ into $w_j$ - not telling how.

Comment: $w_j = T^{-1}\cdot \max\{V_j(t)\, : \,t\in [0,T]\} $ could work as an approximation.